# reduce dataframe rows in python

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, pca

i have dataframe of 8000*1600 , and i want to reduce the number of lines without changing the values, i tried pca but the values has changed
exemple :

```
    a 10 20 30 40
    b 20 70 40 50
    c 10 00 80 40
    d 20 30 99 50
    e 10 20 30 40
    f 59 30 40 50
    g 10 20 30 40
    h 90 30 40 50
    i 91 20 34 18
```

into :

```
    a 10 20 30 40
    c 10 00 80 40
    h 90 30 40 50
    i 91 20 34 18
```

i think explained_variance_ratio_ would handle this with a for loop , any help please

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend reading up about PCA and what it does. The values are different for a very good reason, and if you're trying to prevent that, then you're not doing PCA (you're doing something else, very very incorrect).

Comment: i'm just wondering, my needs are in the exemple , reducing the number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your problem, I think you're confusing the purpose of PCA (**dimensionality reduction)** with a simple dataframe manipulation to **reduce the number of rows**. These are very different things:

**Dimensionality reduction**, which you can get via PCA, would modify the values of your dataframe (that is the point), and is a useful, but not extremely straightforward method of creating/extracting new features from your data for analysis, visualizing high-dimensional data, etc. Take a look at the wikipedia pages on [pca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Applications) and [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction), and see if that is indeed what you want. If that *is* what you want, I suggest you reformulate your question.

**Reducing the number of rows** is something completely different, and is very straightforward in `pandas`. Based on your example, it looks like you want to extract a number of random rows, without modification, from your dataframe. This can be done by the following [`df.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

For example, on your data that you posted the following selects 4 random rows:

```
>>> df.sample(4)
   0   1   2   3   4
0  a  10  20  30  40
2  c  10   0  80  40
7  h  90  30  40  50
5  f  59  30  40  50
```

Comment: sacul . god bless you